# Normal users missing groups

Tags: groups

Using version 4.7.27 and I am having a problem with groups.  A normal user has permission to manage groups.  They create a group, instantly they cant see it, only the initial admin user can see the group, even if I give them administer civiCRM access + manage groups + manage restricted groups, they are unable to see the group.  This appeared to be working fine in 4.7.25 (I setup a test site and had no issues, but using 4.7.27 I cant get it to work at all).  The intention was to use ACL's with the group, but I have since deleted them all with no luck.

Comment: What CMS are you running on? This is important because the CMS can have permissions that affect what users can do.

Comment: Running on Drupal 7